# Formula To Allow Simple Data Entry

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Is it possible to have a formula in an Excel cell that is hidden but that responds to data entered in that cell?

This would ease data entry as the person performing the data entry would not have to edit the formula. The user would simply plug in the correct number then the formula would be applied to the cell.

I believe I can do this with macros, but I don't know if this is the only way. Having a spreadsheet always ask if running macros is OK can be annoying if the spreadsheet is emailed to many different people.

Comment: I guess I can just have another worksheet where the data can be entered. Then only formulas will be used on the worksheet that displays all the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a value and a working formula in the one cell (other than say with a Comment).